Space before superscript and Subscript
Is there a global macro available to add space automatically before every superscript and subscript in math present in an entire document.

No. There is control over space after, but not space before, it is always attached directly to the base.

I am the author of the package altsubsup which provides alternative formats for subscripts and superscripts when used with square brackets, like _[...] or ^[...].
You can define your own command and set it with
\newcommand*{\mysubsupformat}[1]{\,#1}% add a thin space
\SetAltSubSupCommands{\mysubsupformat}

Then all subscripts and superscripts written with square brackets will be formatted with the command \mysubsupformat.
Full example
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}% for align*

\usepackage{altsubsup}
\newcommand*{\mysubsupformat}[1]{\,#1}% add a thin space
\SetAltSubSupCommands{\mysubsupformat}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  x_a &  & x^b &  & x_a^b \\
  x_[a] &  & x^[b] &  & x_[a]^[b]
\end{align*}

\end{document}


But maybe you don't want to rewrite your entire document. Since the altsubsup package save the original definitions of ^ and _ in \altsbsp@standardsub and \altsbsp@standardsup, you can try to hack them (in \AtBeginDocument because they are created there, and with \maketatletter and \makeatother to handle the character @ in macro names):
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\rampsmart@standardsub\altsbsp@standardsub
  \def\altsbsp@standardsub#1{\rampsmart@standardsub{\,#1}}% add a thin space
  \let\rampsmart@standardsup\altsbsp@standardsup
  \def\altsbsp@standardsup#1{\rampsmart@standardsup{\,#1}}% add a thin space
}
\makeatother

Full example:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}% for align*

\usepackage{altsubsup}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\rampsmart@standardsub\altsbsp@standardsub
  \def\altsbsp@standardsub#1{\rampsmart@standardsub{\,#1}}% add a thin space
  \let\rampsmart@standardsup\altsbsp@standardsup
  \def\altsbsp@standardsup#1{\rampsmart@standardsup{\,#1}}% add a thin space
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}



\begin{align*}
  x_a &  & x^b &  & x_a^b
\end{align*}

\end{document}

Obviously, don't use squared forms in this case, they're broken.

Thank you, sounds good to me. Let me check on these macros for my content.

@RampSmart I just saw that the hack gives a Double superscript error when used with a prime symbol, like in x'^a. I'll see if I can find a workaround.

@RampSmart Finally, no new Double superscript error (it was triggered by x'_a^b, this happen also with bare latex). So everything should work fine.
